# Magento2; how to call attributes for upsell products product/list/items.phtml

Tags: magento2.3, product-attribute, up-sells

I need to call some product attributes in the Upsell Products view for Magento 2. This would be in the `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

This is said case;

```
case 'upsell':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell $block */
    if ($exist = count($block->getItemCollection()->getItems())) {
        $type = 'upsell';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'upsell_products_list';
        $title = __('Best alternatives');
        $items = $block->getItemCollection()->getItems();
        $limit = $block->getItemLimit('upsell');
        $shuffle = 0;

        $showAddTo = false;
        $showCart = true;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = true;
        $canItemsAddToCart = true;
    }
break;
```

And in the template I can call the product name, image, sku like this;

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?>
<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?>
```

That works fine, but this doesn't;

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getAttribute('mycustomattribute')); ?>
```

This attribute is visible on frontend and all that, but it doesn't echo anything in this block. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code.

```
$_item->getData("Your_attribute_code");
```

or

```
$_item->getYourAttributeCode();
```

if you still not get the attribute value then got to

```
Stores -> Attributes
```

and edit your attribute and set **Used in Product Listing** to `Yes` under **Storefront Properties**

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I can't believe I hadn't tried this, but `getData` did show it. Thanks!